# iOS: How to localize strings with multiple interpolated parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, internationalization, nslocalizedstring

How do I use NSLocalizedString to build a string with multiple parameters while giving the translator control to change the order if they wish?

An example in my Localizable.string is:

```
"score_out_of"="Your score is %i out of %i";
```

And would be invoked like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"score_out_of", nil), correct, total];
```

But on some locales the grammar rules might dictate that total goes before correct. In Objective C it seems the interpolation order is hard coded.

In other languages this is accomplished by naming the parameters, for example in ruby it would be defined like:

```
out_of: "Your score is %{correct} out of %{total}"
```

And invoked like:

```
I18n('out_of', {total: total, correct: correct})
```

What is the recommended way to accomplish the same thing on iOS / Objective C?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW2

> **Note that you can also use the “n$” positional specifiers such as %1$@ %2$s**

So you can simply create your string as

`"score_out_of"="Your score is %1$i out of %2$i"`

And in other language, it could be

`"score_out_of"="Out of %2$i, your score is %1$i"`